# How to convert SAS code to find duplicates in my data set into R code

Tags: r, sas

I had written the following SAS code to find the duplicated records but now it is required to convert in R. I am not good at R, how can I convert this SAS code to equivalent R code? I had tried this code in R but I think it is not right and not giving me correct results.

Sas Code:

```
data dup; 
set adhb; by id ass_yr ass_mth fields;
if first.ass_mth and last.ass_mth then delete;
run;    

#Dataset relates to  Health Records
ass_mth-assessment month
ass_year--assessment year
fields-just to mention how many fields used
id --character field
Rest of the variables are numeric  

#  R code
    adhb<-arrange(adhb,adhb$NHI,adhb$Ass_yr,adhb$Ass_mth,adhb$fields)
    x %>% group_by(adhb$NHI,adhb$Ass_yr,adhb$Ass_mth,adhb$fields) %>% 
          filter(duplicated(adhb$Ass_mth))
```

Comment: I don't know SAS so I don't know what your code does. Can you describe more? It would also help to show some example data and desired output.

Comment: My sas code is just identifying unique records within each group   (if first.ass_mth and last.ass_mth statement which means we have only one record in this group) and then deleting them so that we can have duplicated records left in our dataset.

Comment: try this `adhb$ass_mth[duplicated(adhb$ass_mth) |duplicated(adhb$ass_mth,fromLast=T)]`

Comment: Please give feedback about answers so the community knows whether the problem is solved or not

Answer (score 0):

You can gourp by your target variable and keep all records that appear more than once:

```
set.seed(0)
adhb <- tibble(ass_mth = sample(letters[1:5], 10, T))

adhb %>% 
  group_by(id, ass_yr, ass_mth) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1)
```

Comment: All four variables mentioned in sas codes are my grouping variables and  records must be grouped by patient ID -then ass_year_ass_mth and then fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a slight variation on the code above given your logic.

```
adhb %>% 
    #sort in order needed
    arrange(id, ass_yr, ass_mth, fields) %>%
    #group by relevant variables
    group_by(id, ass_yr, ass_mth) %>% 
    #filter based on # of records per grouping line
    filter(n() > 1)
```

Comment: why do you think the order is of any importance here?

Comment: Because of how SAS first and last works, note that the OP is using the third variable in their sort list not the fourth. So for the correct order you have to sort first

Comment: Given that they’re not filtering unique you could change yours to have the three variables only but the results would still not necessarily be exactly the same as SAS.

Comment: Aah I see where my misinterpretation of the code is. It would not matter if field changes, right? So your code is just fine but what does the arrange change here? Would any group be smaller/bigger without arrange?
I'm quite curious about it ;)

Comment: No, the results would not differ but the order of the results may and that could affect further results downstream, if order is assumed or implied in any way.